# Apple Rejecting App - "Content cut from display and doesn't fit the iPad"

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I am just really mind-boggled as to why my app has for the 10th time been rejected.

Apple states, that data/display has been cut off when using my app on an iPad. (It is optimised for iPhone, but I know Apple's policy). The keep saying the same thing. But I have attatched a picture of my app's main-screen which users will be fussed about the most. And I don't see any data cut off.

Here is a side by side comparison of my apps, on both iPad and iPhone 6S+:

[image: Here is a side by side comparison of my apps, on both iPad and iPhone 6S+]

I know what you're thinking, yes, the data has been, as Apple put it "cut off" but the data I am displaying is all within a UIScrollView. You simply need to scroll up in order to see all data. Regardless off the device whether it be iPhone 8+, iPhone SE or even an iPad. I just don't understand where the data is "cut-off".

This what Apple have always replied, (starting from latest reply to oldest)-

> Hello,
>
> Thank you for your reply.
>
> However, we noticed your main screen is still not optimized to be
> displayed on iPad. iPhone apps must run at iPhone 2X resolution and
> still be fully functional on an iPad. The user should be able to
> access the same features and content without it being cut off from the
> display
> Additionally, your app does not provide a back button on the search page, >which contributes to a lower quality user experience.
>
> We hope you will make the necessary changes to your app and resubmit for >review. We look forward to reviewing your revised app.
>
> Best regards,
>
> App Store Review
>
> Thank you for resubmitting your application. Upon further review, we
> found the following issues:
>
> We noticed that your app did not run at iPhone resolution when
> reviewed on iPad running iOS 11.0.1.Specifically, we noticed portions
> of your app overlapped or were cut off when displayed on an iPad.
>
> Please see attached screenshots for details.

The screenshots they have attached so not show any "over-lapping" or data being "cut-off". For instance, they screenshot me the UITableViewController. Which boggles my mind.

Either I am missing something or it's going over my head or there is a genuine issue here?

Could someone help me out?

Thank you. It's just really infuriating.

Comment: What about just supporting the iPad? Just take the iPad as an extra large iPhone. Instead of treating it as an iPhone 4 with the screen blown up, with all negative effects.

Comment: I would seccond the suggestion that you make your app universal and make your app support both iPhone and iPad. You also have an option of raising a Developer code-level support issue for assistance from Apple with your rejection. If you do this an engineer will work with you to resolve the issue rather than simply having to resubmit and hope it is accepted this time.

Comment: @gnasher729 Yes, I've decided to do this. Thank you for the recommendation.

Comment: @Paulw11 Yes, I decided to take the advice. Thank you guys. Just find it stupid how Apple nit-pick sometimes.